# RegEx to convert PHP variables into HTML echo snippets

Tags: php, regex

PHP vars can be of the following formats and can contain letters numbers and underscores:

```
$var_1
$var_1[key_1]
$var_1['key_1']
$var_1["key_1"]
$var_1[key_1][key_2]
$var_1['key_1']['key_2']
$var_1["key_1"]["key_2"]
$var_1->property_1
$var_1->property_1->property_2
```

Array and object will never have more than 2 nested elements. Objects won't have methods (i.e. `$var_1->method_1()` is not needed).

I need a RegEx matching them **all**, or a minimum amount of several RegExes, that would convert them into HTML echo snippets in the following format:

```
<?=$1?>
```

Where `$1` is the entire matched string. If possible to add constants to the same RegEx it would be just perfect:

```
CONST_1 into <?=CONST_1?>
```

Comment: If you are trying to obtain the values for all of the variables you can use http://us1.php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for the given examples:

```
\$\w+(?:\[(["']|)\w+\1\]|->\w+){0,2}
```

Replace it with `<?=$0?>` (make sure to use `0`, because `1` is the first capture and not the entire match). I did not include constants, because I think that is rather tricky (how do you know it's a constant and not a reserved keyword - include all keywords?).

Explanation of the regex:

```
\$         # literal $
\w+        # letters, digits, underscores
(?:        # subpattern to match indexing or a member
   \[      # literal [
   (["']|) # a ', a " or nothing (capture it in group 1)
   \w+     # letters, digits, underscores
   \1      # the correct matching closing delimiter
   \]      # literal ]
|          # or
   ->      # literal ->
   \w+     # letters, digits, underscores
){0,2}     # end of subpattern, repeat 0 to 2 times
```

Note that if you use this pattern within PHP, you might have to escape the `'`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! I had to add a few changes: `(\$?\w+(?:\[(["']|)\w+\2\]|->\w+){0,2})` because DreamWeaver doesn't recognize `$0`, but it works just fine now and even matches CONSTANTS too!

Comment: @Geo sure it matches constants, too, now, but it also matches `if` and `return` and `echo` and really any string of letters, digits and underscores it can find (strings, function names and so on).

Comment: yea, i just stumbled over it myself and removed the `?` :-) Thanks again